# imgui v1.60 link errors

Tags: c++, glfw, imgui

I was following a tutorial on opengl, got up to this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nVaQuNXueFw&list=PLlrATfBNZ98foTJPJ_Ev03o2oq3-GGOS2&index=23

But at minute 8 all I get is link errors. 151 link errors that are related to ImGui.
But I don't understand, I have included the header files how come the linker is complaining?

The problem seems to lie in this piece of code:

```
{
    static float f = 0.0f;
    static int counter = 0;
    ImGui::Text("Hello, world!");                           // Display some text (you can use a format string too)
    ImGui::SliderFloat("float", &f, 0.0f, 1.0f);            // Edit 1 float using a slider from 0.0f to 1.0f    
    ImGui::ColorEdit3("clear color", (float*)&clear_color); // Edit 3 floats representing a color

    ImGui::Checkbox("Demo Window", &show_demo_window);      // Edit bools storing our windows open/close state
    ImGui::Checkbox("Another Window", &show_another_window);

    if (ImGui::Button("Button"))                            // Buttons return true when clicked (NB: most widgets return true when edited/activated)
        counter++;
    ImGui::SameLine();
    ImGui::Text("counter = %d", counter);

    ImGui::Text("Application average %.3f ms/frame (%.1f FPS)", 1000.0f / ImGui::GetIO().Framerate, ImGui::GetIO().Framerate);
}
```

I don't know what else one needs to see but here's the entire Application.cpp file:

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>


#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include "types.h"

#include "Renderer.h"
#include "VertexBuffer.h"
#include "IndexBuffer.h"
#include "VertexArray.h"
#include "VertexBufferLayout.h"
#include "Shader.h"
#include "Texture.h"

#include "glm/glm.hpp"
#include "glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp"

#include "imgui/imgui.h"
#include "imgui/imgui_impl_glfw_gl3.h"



int main(void)
{
    GLFWwindow* window;

    /* Initialize the library */
    if (!glfwInit())
        return -1;

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    /* Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context */
    window = glfwCreateWindow(960, 540, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    /* Make the window's context current */
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glfwSwapInterval(1);

    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
        std::cout << "glew failed to init\n";

    std::cout << glGetString(GL_VERSION) << '\n';

    {
        /*float positions[16] =
        {
            -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
             0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
             0.5f,  0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
            -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f
        };*/

        float positions[16] =
        {
            100.f, 100.f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
            200.f, 100.f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
            200.f, 200.f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
            100.f, 200.f, 0.0f, 1.0f
        };

        U32 indices[6]
        {
            0,1,2,
            2,3,0
        };

        GLCall(glEnable(GL_BLEND));
        GLCall(glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA));

        
        VertexArray va;
        VertexBuffer vb(positions, 4 * 4 * sizeof(float));
        VertexBufferLayout layout;
        layout.Push<float>(2);
        layout.Push<float>(2);
        va.AddBuffer(vb, layout);

        IndexBuffer ib(indices, 6);

        glm::mat4 proj = glm::ortho(0.f, 960.f, 0.f, 540.f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
        glm::mat4 view = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(-100, 0, 0));
        glm::mat4 model = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(200, 200, 0));
        glm::mat4 mvp = proj * view * model;

        Shader shader("res/shaders/Basic.shader");
        shader.Bind();
        shader.SetUniform4f("u_Color", 0.8f, 0.3f, 0.8f, 1.0f);
        shader.SetUniformMat4f("u_MVP", mvp);

        Texture texture("res/textures/cherno.png");
        texture.Bind();
        shader.SetUniform1i("u_Texture", 0);

        va.UnBind();
        vb.Unbind();
        ib.Unbind();
        shader.UnBind();

        Renderer renderer;

        ImGui::CreateContext();
        ImGui_ImplGlfwGL3_Init(window, true);
        ImGui::StyleColorsDark();

        bool show_demo_window = true;
        bool show_another_window = false;
        ImVec4 clear_color = ImVec4(0.45f, 0.55f, 0.60f, 1.00f);

        float r = 0.0f;
        float increment = 0.05f;
        /* Loop until the user closes the window */
        while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
        {
            /* Render here */
            renderer.Clear();

            ImGui_ImplGlfwGL3_NewFrame();

            shader.Bind();
            shader.SetUniform4f("u_Color", r, 0.3f, 0.8f, 1.0f);

            renderer.Draw(va, ib, shader);

            if (r > 1.0f)
                increment = -increment;
            if (r < 0.0f)
                increment = -increment;
            r += increment;

            {
                static float f = 0.0f;
                static int counter = 0;
                ImGui::Text("Hello, world!");                           // Display some text (you can use a format string too)
                ImGui::SliderFloat("float", &f, 0.0f, 1.0f);            // Edit 1 float using a slider from 0.0f to 1.0f    
                ImGui::ColorEdit3("clear color", (float*)&clear_color); // Edit 3 floats representing a color

                ImGui::Checkbox("Demo Window", &show_demo_window);      // Edit bools storing our windows open/close state
                ImGui::Checkbox("Another Window", &show_another_window);

                if (ImGui::Button("Button"))                            // Buttons return true when clicked (NB: most widgets return true when edited/activated)
                    counter++;
                ImGui::SameLine();
                ImGui::Text("counter = %d", counter);

                ImGui::Text("Application average %.3f ms/frame (%.1f FPS)", 1000.0f / ImGui::GetIO().Framerate, ImGui::GetIO().Framerate);
            }
            
            ImGui::Render();
            ImGui_ImplGlfwGL3_RenderDrawData(ImGui::GetDrawData());
            

            /* Swap front and back buffers */
            glfwSwapBuffers(window);

            /* Poll for and process events */
            glfwPollEvents();
        }
    }
    ImGui_ImplGlfwGL3_Shutdown();
    ImGui::DestroyContext();
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

Here's what the project directory structure looks like:

[image: Here's what the project directory structure looks like:]

I re-watched the video a few times am I really not making the exact same changes?

I am curious how I messed it up, I feel bad but I honestly don't know what to do.

Here's the some of the output with all the linking errors as requested in the comments: (The full one is too long to post)

```
Build started at 12:50 PM...
1>------ Build started: Project: C++20 console application1, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'LIBCMT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
1>LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
1>Application.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl ImGui::Text(char const *,...)" (?Text@ImGui@@YAXPBDZZ) referenced in function _main
1>imgui.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl ImGui::Text(char const *,...)" (?Text@ImGui@@YAXPBDZZ)
1>imgui_demo.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl ImGui::Text(char const *,...)" (?Text@ImGui@@YAXPBDZZ)
1>Application.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "bool __cdecl ImGui::Button(char const *,struct ImVec2 const &)" (?Button@ImGui@@YA_NPBDABUImVec2@@@Z) referenced in function _main
1>imgui.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "bool __cdecl ImGui::Button(char const *,struct ImVec2 const &)" (?Button@ImGui@@YA_NPBDABUImVec2@@@Z)
1>imgui_demo.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "bool __cdecl ImGui::Button(char const *,struct ImVec2 const &)" (?Button@ImGui@@YA_NPBDABUImVec2@@@Z)
1>Application.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "bool __cdecl ImGui::Checkbox(char const *,bool *)"
```

**UPDATE 1:**

As suggested in the comments and denoted by the linker there are incompatible settings that should not be used together that I don't know about... I didn't think that this would cause errors but it seems it does. Something very strange happened... I changed the Ignore All Libraries setting in linker/input and I got rid of all of the errors.
But then I noticed the language was set to c++14 so I changed that to c++20. I also removed from Aditional Library Directories the path to where the ImGui folder is(I was adding that just in case visual studio is confused by some of the files being in a different folder than the solution folder) and then I got many errors again.
Then I changed back the language and path settings and I am still getting a lot of linking errors and I am really confused...
I can't believe my fricking eyes as I was writing this I changed the setting Ignore All Default libraries to  and then it worked???
What on earth is happening here? It feels like I am going crazy lol.
Man, those who understand what is happening may have a great laugh here... When the setting Ignore All Default libraries is set to yes I get link errors, if I set it to No or  it works...
I am very confused about why it's working now I literally didn't fix anything as far as I am concerned...
So which setting should I use? Both seem to generate the warnings, I guess I am just not fixing the inconsistency and indeed I have no idea what the LIBCMT or MSVCRT are or why I am getting this warning exactly.
When I use the setting recommended by the linker(/NODEFAULTLIB) then I get more errors (532) so I guess that setting was getting defaulted to (/NODEFAULTLIB) and now even if I default it, it changed to not include that flag?
I am very confused about what happened but it seems that /NODEFAULTLIB should not be used. Which wasn't getting used to begin with but I was getting errors. How is that possible? Can you even believe me?

Comment: Please read ["What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix).

Comment: Impossible to help without seeing the actual errors and what flags you used to compile. It's probably amateur errors.

Comment: Ok, I will add all of it, although I don't understand how it's any different from what I already described. I don't know exactly what flags are used, how does one see that in visual studio?

Comment: Do the *.cpp files in the imgui folder get compiled?

Comment: Looks like you're trying to link your project against multiple versions of the C runtime (static & dll).  Use either LIBCMT or MSVCRT not both.  If you have obtained 3rd party libraries from somewhere make sure they match the settings for your project.

Comment: ***I don't know exactly what flags are used, how does one see that in visual studio?*** Visual Studio does not automatically link with external libraries. To link you had to add changes to your linker settings or use CMake or similar to have it generate your VS project files. If you don't even know where the settings are you likely didn't change them to link. On top of this the `warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'LIBCMT' conflicts` and `warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRT' conflicts` warnings represent a serious problem in your settings.

Comment: Alright, what's the problem with my settings? I will google for that, perhaps I can find it by myself. There is no linking with any library I mean not for ImGui because the youtube tutorial didn't do any such thing and it worked. He just used the cpp and header files in the project directly so I think when doing that no linking would be necessary(it would be automatic, much like when writing your own cpp files)
But I still don't know what flags I use when I link to external libraries, I just add the include paths and the .lib files to the linker.

Comment: Now I am curious what these flags do and where they are... I am still searching, I have found where I can disable the default libraries which seems to be what the linker warning suggests me to do but why was there a problem in the first place? What is LIBCMT and MSVCRT and why are they now conflicting? I didn't change anything... actually I did a bit because I may have changed some settings for x64 platform but for Win32 I think it switched to the defaults or something... So perhaps it was changed that way but still shouldn't by default something that is conflicting not be active same time?

Comment: You definitely don't want to remove the default libraries for this. How much did you mess up with your project? Perhaps try recreating it from scratch?

Comment: Also, if you're replying to someone, add `@username` to a comment to send a notification.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thanks for the suggestion I definitely should be adding @username!
Recreating it from scratch would take a lot of time for me. I am not sure if I messed up something or not, and if I did mess up some setting starting from scratch may end up using the same settings so it wouldn't fix that. Some strange things happened which I updated the post to try to explain what happened. It now works but I literally did almost nothing to fix it... I did change that linker setting but now even if I change it back to default it still works.  I also didn't fix the warnings which I don't know how

Comment: You could share your project files, maybe somebody will spot the error (I wouldn't get my hopes up, msbuild is a messy build system, I doubt anybody would willingly debug it). But setting up a project from scratch is a useful skill, so I'd get used to that. Also learning a better build system (CMake or Meson) would be good too, you'll get more help with CMake that with msbuild.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat For some strange reason I thought you meant to remake it from scratch. If I copy-paste the existing code then it would still take me a lot of time but I would do it to find out why it's not working and try to make it to work. However, if the issue is the settings then if anyone points out what settings in particular should I check I would do that or I could also copy paste the settings if one showed me images of what they should look like.
I am not sure how to learn what you are suggesting but I can google and try to learn how to use CMake thatI know the bare basics of (if even)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat How do I even upload files here? I will upload it although I doubt anyone would be curious enough for this... But I guess they could get the file and load it in Visual studio. Is the project file enough for this or is the solution also needed? Visual studio seems to be able to open other file but I just thought that perhaps it's because they are in the same folder. I will try to upload both but I don't really know how

Comment: There's no way to upload files directly, you either upload to pastebin, or if the file is short enough, add it is at text to the question. I don't think anybody would bother opening it in VS (so the solution isn't needed), but maybe somebody will be able to spot the error directly in the file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256376/discussion-between-chris-and-holyblackcat).